# Can I map to a non default constructor with ModelMapper without defining any custom TypeMaps or so?

Tags: java, modelmapper

I work with immutable objects. I would like to map from one to another immutable object with `org.modelmapper.ModelMapper`. If I do that just like this I'm getting an exception
`Failed to instantiate instance of destination com.MyImmutableObject. Ensure that com.MyImmutableObject has a non-private no-argument constructor`

As I've declared all fields as final, there won't be a default constructor.
Also I don't want to declare custom typemaps for the ModelMapper which just makes the whole thing blow up and more complex than usefull. Is there an easy way to tell the ModelMapper, to map directly to a constructor?

Comment: Check if this is helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264214/using-modelmapper-how-do-i-map-to-a-class-with-no-default-no-args-constructor

Comment: @Gaurav Thanks, but this exactly what I dislike :) I don't want to make a TypeMap which makes everything much more complex and unreadable.